# Laravel 5.6 & saving array values

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm totally new with Laravel and trying to create simple invoice form (just drafted few fields of it till now). Header of the Invoice is saved in db properly, the first InvoiceItem also. However, if I'm adding more than one row in a table with Invoice items, only the first value is saved in db.

This is InvoiceItem row:

```
<tr>
<td>
<select class="form-control name" name="productname[]">
<option value="0" selected="true" disabled="true">Select Product</option>
@foreach($product_lists as $key=>$p)
<option value="{!!$key!!}">{!!$p!!}</option>
@endforeach                                             
</td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-line qty" name="qty[]"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-line price" name="price[]"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-line total" name="total[]"></td>
<td><a href="#" class="remove">-<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a></td>
</tr>
```

This is jquery to add another InvoiceItem row:

```
function addRow(){
var tr='<tr>'+
'<td>'+
'<select class="form-control name" name="productname[]">'+
'<option value="0" selected="true" disabled="true">Select Product</option>'+
'@foreach($product_lists as $key=>$p)'+
'<option value="{!!$key!!}">{!!$p!!}</option>'+
'@endforeach'+                                      
'</td>'+
'<td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-line qty" name="qty[]"></td>'+
'<td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-line price" name="price[]"></td>'+
'<td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-line total" name="total[]"></td>'+
'<td><a href="#" class="remove">-<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a></td>'+
'</tr>';
$('tbody').append(tr);
};
```

This is my controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
$salesinvoice = $this->validate(request(), [
'invoice_no' => 'required'
]);
SalesInvoice::create($salesinvoice);
foreach ($request->productname as $key=>$v) {
$data=array(
'product_id'=>$request->$v,
'qty'=>$request->qty[$key],
'price'=>$request->price[$key],
'total'=>$request->total[$key]
);
SalesInvoiceItem::insert($data);    
};
```

I would appreciate any guidance/hints how to solve it.

Edit: This is the request:

```
array:6 [▼
  "_token" => "xw1dkpYSjUNql1mHJLrreieRgcPk5nafpuvnawu0"
  "invoice_no" => "1000"
  "productname" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "1"
  ]
  "qty" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "5"
  ]
  "price" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "25"
  ]
  "total" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "125"
  ]
]
```

Looks like the issue is with the form itself, not with the controller, right?

Comment: You can't simply use Laravel blade directives (`@foreach`) in your jQuery. Take a look at the rendered DOM once you add a new row.

Comment: Hmm... it works fine if i'm hardcoding this rows in html, but if i'm adding them dynamically with jquery or insertRow, it's not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `$v` instead of `$request->$v` when insert the data.

Replace the following:

```
'product_id' => $request->$v,
```

By:

```
'product_id' => $v
```

Comment: Yeah, u r right. However it solved other problem (not inserting product_id into invoiceitems table). 
Still the array is not working - only first row is inserted into db.

Comment: @FreelanceX What do you mean?

Comment: Ok - the idea is to save invoice header and then all invoice items (lines) with products. However, it always save only the header and the first invoice item (line) - despite i added more then one row in this nested table...

Comment: @FreelanceX Can you do add a `dd(request()->all());` to your question so I can see the data that has been sent?

Comment: @FreelanceX As you see, there's only product item being sent.